# Using IIS Express to host a website (temporarily)

Tags: .net, iis, iis-express

I have a website (MVC3), which for developement is hosted in IIS Express. (I've run into a bug of Cassini Devserver and had to upgrade...)
Now, I'm wondering, is it possible to let other machines on my local net (behind router) see the site as hosted on my machine? (e.g. If I write http://my.local.ip:port into a browser on the same LAN as I am will the page load?)

Comment: @John Saunders: Did. Not working.

Comment: care to share the results? What does "not working" mean?

Comment: it meant the page didn't load (server not responding), so I'm guessing  the IIS Express doesn't answer non-localhost request (like Cassini). But since IIS Express IS a full server it should be able to.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

By default IIS Express serves only localhost requests. To serve external requests edit `applicationhost.config` file (located in `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\`) and change `localhost` to `'*'` or your machine name. (remember for non-localhost binding you must be running as administrator or set URL acl as an administrator and then run iisexpress as non-administrator)

Comment: I've located my site in the config xml, and changed `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44886:localhost" />` to `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44886:*" />`. Then added url acl in admin mode (`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:44886/ user=\Everyone`). Now, when I press F5 in visual studio, I get "Unable to start IIS Express".

Comment: run this command "netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:44886/ user=Everyone" and try to start it again(press F5). This should work. Following link may also help http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1005/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express/

Comment: fyi, you must restart the service for this to take effect, else you get a 503 error. works perfect for me after svc restart.

Comment: Url from @vikomall has changed to http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express

Comment: @KevinWon What is the name of the service that I should restart?

Comment: @CiaranBruen: Both links point to the same page (now, anyway).

Comment: @vikomall: By "run this command" do you mean in cmd? If so, I'm surprised that mashing F5 does anything after that...

Comment: I had to add an additional binding in the `applicationhost.config` file in stead of modifying the existing one. Otherwise visual studio keeps creating a different one. And couldn't use * so simply used local IP. Also, had to run VS in administrator

Comment: Note: the user/group "Everyone" has to be localized. I.e. for Swedish Windows, write "Alla" instead.

Comment: Don't also forget to configure your windows firewall to let the your port pass.

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, you can use something like [AnalogX's PortMapper](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/pmapper/Freeware.htm) to act as a small loopback proxy to *tunnel* privately localhost bound ports to publicly open ports.

For example,

- **IISExpress** is locally bound to **localhost:8080**
- **PortMapper** port **9090** is configured to relay traffic to **localhost:8080**

Effectively, any connection on port **9090** (opened by **PortMapper**) will be tunneled to **localhost:8080**; thereby bypassing all the netsh nonsense which can be a pain sometimes.

Below is my configuration:

[image: PortMapper configuration]

The benefit of using this proxying method is that it does not permanently expose an open **IISExpress** port on the local dev box.

Rarely, there are times when I want to open the port publicly for meetings; but most of the time, the port should closed and only be accessible by localhost. Modifying firewall rules on the router every time is a pain. Here's how I have things setup:

- My router firewall forwards **9090** port to **PortMapper**
- **PortMapper** only continues proxying the traffic to **IISExpress** (listening on **8080**) only if **PortMapper** is running.

#### Note

Make sure to close out all the **PortMapper** windows for any changes to take effect.

#### Note 2

As others have described, you might need to adjust the **IISExpress** bindings for your application in

```
 My Documents\IISExpress\applicationhost.config
 project\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```

to something like:

```
<bindings>
  <!-- bindingInformaiton format:
          IPToBindTo:Port:DNSHostName -->

  <!--OLD:
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:localhost"/>-->

  <!--Change '*' to 127.0.0.1 and remove 'localhost' right of the port number
      to avoid invalid DNS hostname errors -->
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="127.0.0.1:8080:" />

</bindings>
```

Comment: The idea is very good (I will surely use this proxy for other scenarios), but it doesn't work in this case. IIS Express just gives you this back when trying to access the site by its IP:

`HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.`

Comment: I updated my answer; hopefully that solves your "hostname" invalid error.

Answer (score 7):

I believe there are three steps to making this succesful:

1) Add a dns entry or hosts entries so other machines can lookup the dev machine's ip address

2) Add a binding to applicationhost.config  in %userprofile/documents/IISExpress/Config like so

```
<site name="MobileDashboard(2)" id="7">
                <bindings>
                    ...
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:yourport#:yourmachinendnsname" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

3) Run the command found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express) to allow incoming requests:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://yourmachinendnsname:yourport#/ user=everyone
```

Comment: So is this what I need to add to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

<my IP Address> localhost

...such as:

192.168.125.50 localhost

?

Answer (score 4):

The answer in this thread is great, it just leaves out the firewall exceptions.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IIS Express (non-SSL)" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=8000

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IIS Express (SSL)" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=44300
```

Sourced from comments @ http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The Custom Rule trick in Fiddler from http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/12/15/how-to-use-fiddler-on-localhost.aspx worked for me eventually.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can configure as many sites using iis express for local lan use here is link [Accessing local sites from Lan IIS Express](http://www.ilmlinks.com/Pages/siteonlan) which explain how to achieve this.

Comment: I tried this, it did not work for me. This would be the cleanest answer if I could apply it. The extra application (the one with LAN IP address) does not show up in IIS Express under my site, only the localhost one. Could there be a step missing? I did exit / restart IIS Express. My `applicationhost.config` is looking like `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:23297:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:23297:192.168.1.254" />`