# Setting up IIS Express to accept local connections on visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, iis-7, visual-studio-2012

I made a web service with MVC4 and running on localhost with IIS express seems fine. 
But I need to access from outside, so I'll have to use a local IP.

I've found out that IIS Express only accepts incoming requests with localhost specification in the header.

I've tried to go to the "applicationhost.config"  and change the

```
binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:4019:localhost"
```

to this:

```
 binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:4019:10.250.38.85"
```

but now visual studio wont let me run IIS Express saying its unable to launch.

I've also been wandering around IIS manager trying to attach one of the websites to the project without success.

What am I forgetting?

I'll also need this to use SSL and not sure how to configure

I've tried to edit IIS Express applicationhost.config and change binding protocol="http" to https but then vs2012 couldnt even load the project saying it couldnt create the virtual directory

Is there a way to change IIS express to normal IIS 7 so I can use the manager?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235826/using-iis-express-to-host-a-website-temporarily

Comment: i add seen it before but thanks still cant put the ip to work... only the alias which works with lan. Guess the ip issue might be something internal from the network architecture/virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign IP in the iis as follows:

[image]

Then you need to publish your website into this iis website. it will work....

Comment: i guess i might have a problem if i use ssl i have to assign an ip but i cannot use a local ip, all i can use is an alias

Comment: Also it seems the configurations from IIS express and IIS 7.0 are different because the sites ive created in IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config dont show up