# Replacing IIS Express for IIS at visual studio 2012

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, iis-express

IIS Express is giving me too many problems with the configurations such as enabling SSL or using a Local Ip

My visual studio2012 project only allows me to use IIS Express and not regular IIS so my ISS manager is not syncronized with my my project and I'm having a hard time setting up everything.

I've tried to configure a website in IIS manually but the project Bin folder isn't what I need to target to deploy to Service.

How can I set visual studio 2012 to run using regular IIS instead the Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a site up in IIS on a different port from the IIS Express port and then manually attach the debugger to w3wp.exe when debugging.

Comment: thats probably what ill end up doing, I didn't found a way to integrate the IIS 7 in visual studio directly. But just for fun lets see what other people say before i accept your answer

Comment: just for those who might end up here, I've also heard about few open source projects that allow you to control the IIS Express configurations a little bit more. Sorry i haven't search for it but knowing they exist might be usefull

Comment: Just out of interest, why can't you IIS from Visual Studio? Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator? You need to for IIS debugging

Comment: Yes, I always run as administrator. I need to create some webservices for several different mobile devices. IIS Express expects to receive requests only from localhost. I was able to change the localhost address at applicationHost.config to use an alias instead which allowed me to access to the webservices from the emulators. I couldn't use a local IP because then VS was give me some error messages. I also tried to change applicationHost.config to use https instead http which also cause the vs2012 to give an error on creating virtual directorys or something, can't remember.

Comment: related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087964/setting-up-iis-express-to-accept-local-connections-on-visual-studio-2012/15090975#15090975

Answer (score 2):

what o/s do you have?

within the project properites, web section, you can uncheck iisexpress and use the real iis if your o/s has it

Comment: This may work for Web Application projects. It's a tad d ifferent for Web Site Projects. 

For those, you choose "Start Options" in the web site context menu, then you are offered "Default Web Server" or "Customer Web Server".

If you have preconfigured a site under IIS, you can enter the url for it there.

I also entered the physical path for the IIS site under "MSBuild Options" -> "Output Folder". This is also on the "Start Options" dialog.

I have had some success with this approach. Certainly you drop straight into debug assuming you have a suitable breakpoint set up.