# use web service on local VM for testing with iOS App in simulator

Tags: asp.net, ios, web-services, virtual-machine

I want to test / debug some of my new web services using my Windows 8 VM (using VM Fusion).

Is it possible for the iOS Simulator to make requests to the localhost that is running on the same machine in the VM?

This would be a HUGE time saver for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible. I don't run VM Fusion, but I do run Parallels with Windows 7 on my Mac from time to time. Each VM gets its own IP address. So, rather than referencing the VM as localhost, you would refer to it by the IP address. After you start up Windows, run **ipconfig** from the command line. That will show you the IP address of the VM which you can reference from the iOS simulator.

Comment: yep got it, had to run VS2012 as an adminsitrator and put my IP in the config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235826/using-iis-express-to-host-a-website-temporarily