# Can I use IIS Express to host a C# ASP.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

I have a website that I am making and was wondering if I can use IIS Express to host my website? I need it to be accessible for 2 people, myself and my instructor. It runs locally at the moment while I am still creating it, but to turn it in it needs to be live basically. Is this possible and if so, whats the way to go about it?

Comment: What sort of issues did you have when you tried this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235826/using-iis-express-to-host-a-website-temporarily

Comment: I haven't really tried it yet, i was just wondering if it was possible  and worth checking into since I would prefer not to buy my own domain name. And thanks System, I will check that link.