# How to test app dynamically changing based on domain

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multilingual, iis-express

I am developing a multi-lingual project/web-site in visual studio and use IISExpress for development.

To switch between the different language version of the website I use the third level domain eg: en.maxfavilli.com, it.maxfavilli.com, de.maxfavilli.com, etc...

I can set-up IIS and use IIS on my development machine in place of IISExpress, but I would prefer to stick on the lighter IISExpress. My problem is, how do I test that using IISexpress?

IISExpress always execute on localhost:port, can I configure something like it.localhost, en.localhost, de.localhost? How?

How does other developers handle this problem in VS+IISExpress?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235826/using-iis-express-to-host-a-website-temporarily - it covers a lot of useful info, including using Fiddler to map random hosts names to localhost.