# VS2015 Web Project accessible from LAN

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

I'm not able to make my VS2015 Web Project visible on LAN.

I changed `C:\Users\%user_name%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`with

> binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57026:127.0.0.1"

but when I add as tutorials suggest

> binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57026:*

and try to start the project I get **"Failed to register URL ..... acces denied"**

I also added the firewall exception.

What can I do ?

Comment: Install IIS on your machine and deploy the project to it? IIS Express is designed for developers to easily debug and test on their own machines, not for serving up pages to others.

Comment: Yes, but I need a workaround for LAN , can it be done with port forward ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using IIS Express to host a website (temporarily)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235826/using-iis-express-to-host-a-website-temporarily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's happened because VS2015 use another applicationhost.config located in a hidden folder in your project folder (.vs).

Try delete applicationhost.config file from .vs folder and restart VS 2015.
After this, configure port that you want use on Project properties on VS2015.

I think it'll solve your problem.

PS. I can't test this scenarios now.